# Install specific version of hadoop using Ambari

Tags: hadoop, ambari, hdp

I am new to HDP installation using Ambari. I want to install Hadoop 2.9.0 using Ambari web installation. My Ambari version is 2.7.0.0 and I am using HDP 3.0 which has Hadoop 3.1.0. But I need to install Hadoop 2.9.0. Can someone please let me know if this can be done? And how can this be achieved?

I have not started the cluster installation yet and I'm done with Ambari installation.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Ambari uses pre-defined software stacks.

HDP does not offer any stack with Hadoop 2.9.0

You would therefore need to manually install that version of Hadoop yourself, although you can still manage the servers (but not the Hadoop configuration) using Ambari

In any case, there's little benefit to installing a lower version of the software, plus you won't get Hortonworks support if you do that

Comment: If I manually install hadoop, does it reflect in Ambari or there are some configurations? Links for configurations will be helpful (if any).

Comment: I don't have links because I've never personally tried this, and I've only installed Ambari Agents manually, then use Puppet for Hadoop configs. I don't think Ambari can "manage a custom Hadoop" installed anywhere. Plus other services might fail to install because Ambari won't recognize that Hadoop is actually running anywhere

Comment: Can you explain what features of 2.9 you need that aren't available either in 3.1.0 or that you can't use HDP 2.6.x for instead?

Comment: I had a discussion with the team and we are going to use 3.x HDP for installation. Your input was much useful to me.

Comment: That's a good choice considering Docker runtime support is added to YARN and Erasure Coding in HDFS allows you to save more disk space.